# MDF file is close to 900gb but my calculation of reserved table space is less than 30gb... what am I missing?

Tags: sql-server

In a nutshell, my server is running out of free hard drive space so I ran the script found here to get an idea of tables I could possibly delete old data from:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10932
but when I got the results it seems that deleting old data doesn't seem to be my solution. I have a feeling there is something else I should be aware of here...

results from sp_spaceused

```
database_name   database_size   unallocated space
prod            993333.19 MB    94327.32 MB


reserved        data         index_size unused
834819768 KB    833565632 KB 1065480 KB 188656 KB
```

The results of my "find big tables" script:

```
reserved_KB     data_KB     index_size_KB   unused_KB
27,257,368      26,126,568  1,003,184       127,616
```

Comment: Do you have heaps in this database?

Comment: If you have tables without clustered indexes, and are deleting rows from those tables on an ongoing basis, those deleted rows will in fact still be using allocated space in the file.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide There shouldn't be any, I wasn't the original architect so I may need to go through and check

Comment: Please do that and if you have any rebuild those as a start.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I've found quite a few heaps and have been adding indexes, I've also run shrinkfile & rebuilt indexes based on JohnEisbrener's recommendation but the file size is getting worse.

Comment: Can you post output from `sp_spaceused`?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: (Added to original post for formatting's sake) database_name database_size unallocated space
prod 993333.19 MB 94327.32 MB reserved data index_size unused
834819768 KB 833565632 KB 1065480 KB 188656 KB

Comment: why do you say "deleting old data doesn't seem to be my solution"? Can you post the results of the script to find big tables? According to your sp_spaceused, the space is actually being used, that's why the shrink did not reclaim anything back.

Comment: @FelipeFerreira - I've added the summed totals of the results

Comment: is this your largest table? I think the easiest way for you to check this without using third-party scripts is to just open your database, expand the Tables folder. Click in View > Object Explorer Details. You will see a list of all your tables in the right panel, click on the Title section, over Name for instance. and chose Data Space Used, Index Space Used and Row Count. This way you can see all your tables how much space they are using. sp_spaceused says you have 800Gb on data. so you either have lots and lots of small tables or you should have one bigger than the 26gb one u posted

Comment: @FelipeFerreira I spot checked a few tables in the Object Explorer and it reflects what I see in my "find big tables" script. I have about 250 tables total and the "reserved_kb" sum is just over 27gb... Still not sure where the other 750+ gb is...

Comment: Found the missing GB, see mathewb's comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to view the tables using the most space in your database is to run the canned Disk Usage by Top Tables report that is available through SSMS. Right click on the database in question, select Reports, and then select that report.

Comment: OK we have a winner! this report is showing one table as being much larger than reported in my "find big tables" script, and it just happens to be the 750+ gb I was not finding anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

Since it sounds like you purged data from you tables, the next step is to release the free space within the datafile (.mdf) back to the OS.  You can do this via a [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql) statement.

If this doesn't result in releasing sufficient disk back to the OS, you should rebuild indexes on those tables you performed heavy purge operations against in case they are heap tables and then re-issue the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command.

I would suggest leaving 20 - 30% free space in the mdf, which if I'm reading the question right, should be 36GB - 40GB in your case. This will avoid growth operations from occurring in the near future.

Finally, after the `SHRINKFILE` operation completes, you'll want to [REBUILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql) any heavily fragmented indexes as the `SHRINKFILE` operation will cause fragmentation for any indexes that were stored toward the tail end of the data file.

**EDIT:** So it seems your calculation of reserved table space (as referenced in the question header) is off by a significant margin based on the comments on this answer.  In this case, what I would suggest you do is run the following statement to get an idea of what's using your disk space:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR (4000), @ExecString NVARCHAR ( 4000)

DECLARE dbCursor CURSOR
FOR
        SELECT name
        FROM sys .databases
        WHERE name LIKE '%'

CREATE TABLE ##tmpAllDBs
(
     DBID               INT,
     DatabaseName     SYSNAME,
     Name               SYSNAME,
     FileName          SYSNAME,
     Size               INT,
     UsedSpace          INT,
     ID                    INT,
     FileGroup          SYSNAME
)

SET @String = '
USE [?]

DECLARE     @PageSize     FLOAT
SELECT     @PageSize = v.low/1024.0
FROM     [master].[dbo].[spt_values] v
WHERE     v.number=1
          AND v.type=''E''

CREATE TABLE #tmpspc
(     Fileid               INT,
     FileGroup          INT,
     TotalExtents     INT,
     UsedExtents          INT,
     Name               SYSNAME,
     FileName          NCHAR(520)
)
INSERT #tmpspc
EXEC (''DBCC ShowFileStats'')

CREATE TABLE #tmplogspc
(     DatabaseName     SYSNAME,
     LogSize               FLOAT,
     SpaceUsedPerc     FLOAT,
     Status               BIT
)
INSERT #tmplogspc
EXEC (''DBCC SQLPerf(LogSpace)'')

INSERT INTO ##tmpAllDBs
SELECT     db_id() AS dbID,
          db_name() AS [DatabaseName],
          RTRIM(s.name) AS [Name],
          RTRIM(s.filename) AS [FileName],
          (s.size * @PageSize) AS [Size],
          CAST(tspc.UsedExtents * CONVERT(FLOAT,64) AS FLOAT) AS [UsedSpace],
          CAST(s.fileid AS INT) AS [ID],
          RTRIM(g.groupname) AS [FileGroup]
FROM     [dbo].[sysfilegroups] AS g
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[sysfiles] AS s
               ON s.groupid=CAST(g.groupid AS INT)
          INNER JOIN #tmpspc tspc
               ON tspc.Fileid = CAST(s.fileid AS INT)

UNION

SELECT     db_id() AS dbID,
          db_name() AS [DatabaseName],
          RTRIM(s.name) AS [Name],
          RTRIM(s.filename) AS [FileName],
          (s.size * @PageSize) AS [Size],
          (tspclog.LogSize * tspclog.SpaceUsedPerc * 10.24)
               / ( SELECT     COUNT(s_sub.name)
                    FROM     [dbo].[sysfiles] s_sub
                    WHERE     s_sub.groupid = 0)
          AS [UsedSpace],
          CAST(s.fileid AS INT) AS [ID],
          ''LOG FILE'' AS FileGroup
FROM     [dbo].[sysfiles] AS s
          INNER JOIN #tmplogspc tspclog
               ON tspclog.DatabaseName = db_name()
WHERE     (s.groupid = 0)

DROP TABLE #tmpspc
DROP TABLE #tmplogspc
'
--EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @String

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR (128)
OPEN dbCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor
INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     SELECT @ExecString = REPLACE( @String, '?', @name )
        EXECUTE (@ExecString )

        FETCH NEXT FROM dbCursor
        INTO @name
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor because you've finished traversing all it's data
CLOSE dbCursor
DEALLOCATE dbCursor

SELECT DBID , DatabaseName , Name, FileName, Size /1024.0 AS SizeMB, UsedSpace /1024.0 AS UsedSpaceMB,
     (1.0 * UsedSpace)/(1.0 * Size) AS PercentUsed , ID, FileGroup
FROM ##tmpAllDBs
ORDER BY 2, 8

DROP TABLE ##tmpAllDBs
```

This returns results that show how much size a file is using according to the OS (`SizeMB`), how much data is actually contained within the file (`UsedSpaceMB`) and some other information about the data files.  The script is ugly, but it works all the way back to SQL 2000.

With this output in had, what I would do is look for any files on User Databases where the `PercentUsed` column is low and the database is not `tempdb` (I'll talk about what to do with tempdb further below), and then run `DBCC SHRINKFILE` operations against said files.  This will give back the OS some space, but by no means does this mean your job is done.

Once this is complete, the next step is to identify what data you can purge or which objects you can drop.  Purge old data, drop [unused indexes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/256/discovering-unused-indexes/), and then rerun the script and see what else can be reduced in size.  Again, rebuilding indexes is recommended, but as you've already seen, Index Rebuild operations may cause data files to grow so you may have to weigh if a defragmented index is worth the extra consumption of disk space.

Other options available to you will depend on your SQL Server Version and Edition.  If you're running Enterprise or SQL 2016 Standard SP1 or later, you can take advantage of [Table Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index).  This can help reduce the space used within your data files as well.

If you see that tempdb is consuming a large amount of space which is relatively unused, reduce the the size of the tempdb files, but make sure that if you have multiple `.mdf` files, you shrink them all to the same size as per [MS's recommended guidelines](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527(v=sql.105).aspx).  Another word about tempdb, shrinking it is often an act of futility because there's often activity occurring within the database, so you may have to restart the instance to get these files to shrink down as desired.  Here's [MS's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307487/how-to-shrink-the-tempdb-database-in-sql-server) on the various ways to shrink tempdb.

Another possibility is that you have non-database related clutter on your drive(s).  In this case, simply deleting these files may be the fix for your issue.  I find using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) helps quickly identify where some of the larger files are.  Be sure you know what you're deleting though.  Sometimes there are lots of "seemingly worthless" files sitting in hidden directories, such as the [WinSxS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx) folder that look like they could be quickly deleted.  Don't recklessly delete files; make sure you only purge files you know are safe to remove.

Finally, ask for money and buy some additional storage.  Your server just may be at capacity and it's time for an upgrade.  Hardware isn't always the answer, but sometimes it can be the best answer.

Comment: I actually didn't purge any, I stopped when I noticed I would only gain a few gb according to the script I posted.

Comment: @msimmons If you've got a DB that is consuming 900GB of disk space, but is only using 30GB of it, a `SHRINKFILE` operation against the `.mdf` file may be the only thing you need to do.

Comment: @msimmons, what does `reserved` report when you run `EXEC sp_spaceused;` in the database? If that shows 30GB as the title of your question suggests, follow the steps suggested in John's answer. You could try SHRINKFILE with only TRUNCATEONLY first and, if that frees enough space, don't bother with the target size. That will avoid introducing database fragmentation.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - shrinkfile took some time, however the file size doesn't appear to have changed.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - rebuilt the indexes last night, the file size is larger than when we started.

Comment: @msimmons Check the edited answer for some additional information.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - Thank you for all that information, I will read over it a couple times. In the mean time I wanted to post the results of my large database from your script: SizeMB = 909581, UsedSpaceMB = 815574.812500, PercentUsed = 0.896648910322445 So maybe I'm reading/using the "find large tables" script wrong and I simply need to redefine the business rules on how much data we retain (or more drives, but I have a feeling the data will be dropped before they drop money).